# How to get the externally shared user's profile information for one drive using Microsoft Graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

To get External user information if we share the file with specific people through link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following end point for fetching external users in your AD:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=userType eq 'Guest'
```

make sure that you have to select **beta** version of microsoft graph for additional user properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the external user list, you can use "/users?$filter=userType eq 'Guest'" resolve your issue.

If you want to get the access log of share file through link:
No matter you use OneDrive or OneDrive for business, we cannot use Graph API to get the user who have access the share file through link.

If you share the Team site's document, we can use [JSOM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-retrieve-user-profile-properties-by-using-the-javascript-object-model-in) to get the user profile first and store it to the access log. Then use the [get user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get) api to get the external user info.

If you share the document from OneDrive/OneDrive for business, we cannot assign our custom access log and no known Graph API for this too. You can submit an feature request in the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/), meanwhile, you can try to see the [audit logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/securitycompliance/search-the-audit-log) first.